# Boundary operator product rule

Tags: general-topology

The definitions I'm working with:

Suppose $(Q, \tau)$ is a topological space. A **boundary point** of a set $S \subseteq Q$ is either a point $q$ inside $S$ such that each neighbourhood of $q$ contains a point $r$ outside $S$, or a point $q$ outside $S$ such that each neighbourhood of $q$ contains a point $r$ inside $S$. The **boundary** of a set $S \subseteq Q$, written $\partial S$, is the set of boundary points of $S$.

Suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are (possibly empty) subsets of $Q$. My question: is it true in general that $\partial(S_1 \cap S_2) = (\partial S_1 \cap S_2) \, \cup \, (S_1 \cap \partial S_2)$? If so, how would I prove it? The equation also looks like the product rule; is this related to the derivative in any way?

Comment: There is a product rule for boundary operators: $$\partial(A\times B)=(\partial A \times B) \cup (A\times \partial B)$$ where $\times$ is the Cartesian product.

Comment: I can't argue with the def'n of $\partial S$ in the question. But it can more easily stated as $\partial S=\bar S \cap \overline  {Q\backslash S}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: In the space $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology consider the sets $S_1=\Bbb Q$ and $S_2=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. Verify that each has all of $\Bbb R$ as boundary, but their intersection, being empty, has empty boundary.

Answer (score 0):

No, it fails if you take $S_1=S_2=B$ (open ball in euclidean space, say).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/663196)

Comment: @Babai Depends on how you define providing an answer? The question was: Is it true that ...etc..  My answer is no, with a counter-example. But true that I could equally well have left it is as a comment.